# Counting columns with if conidition in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Counting only columns in which, Buy_Rate is more than Sell_Rate.

My query is not resulting as per expected, it is resulting me wrong.

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$losing_trades_count = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->where('buy_rate', '<', 'sell_rate')->get()->count();
```

**Inverse**: If sell_rate is more than buy_rate then only, count the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `whereColumn`

```
$losing_trades_count = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                                 ->whereColumn('buy_rate', '<', 'sell_rate')
                                 ->count();
```

Also there is no need to call `get()` when you need `count()` from query builder

Comment: Perfect answered, I am getting correct and what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

laravel eloquent `where` don't support comparing columns. so you need use raw SQL in order to compair two columns. you can do something like,

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$losing_trades_count = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->whereRaw('buy_rate < sell_rate')->get()->count();
```

hope this helps!

Comment: this is also perfect result. Thank you very much...! I am learning from different way.